# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I updated my support library from r20 to r21, now when I run my app I get this error in `super.onCreate` of my main activity :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Theme_windowActionBar
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:145)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:139)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
    at (packageName).Main.onCreate(Main.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my theme.xml :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item> ... </item>
</style>
```

in manifest :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

what is the problem ?

thanks

Comment: what theme does your app use and parent from?

Comment: @petey, post updated ..., It was working before update

Comment: wats ur `target SDK` and `compile SDK` version??

Comment: min=11, Target&compile=21,BTW I've installed API 21 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

It happened same to me when I update SDK. If you have version 21 of library "Android Support Library" this bug occurs. I don't know what is the reason but last release make this bug.

You can solve it by downloading previous version of "Android Support Library" (r20) from here: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r20.zip, and using it in your project.

You are welcome!

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Did quite a bit searching but could not find any real fix. So in the end I rolled back to R20. It is not ideal but it works for now. I think the problem is related with the new Material theme google is promoting on 5.0. In my opinion if you only need to support API 14 and above, the support libraries are causing more trouble than solving them.

Comment: If u r not strictly targeting sdk 21, you can get away with the error temporarily by setting targetSDK to less then 21(say 19) in manifest, your build tool version remaining 21.

Answer (score 1):

I have compared `support_v7_appcompat` (version 20) with `support_v7_appcompat` (version 21). In `res/values/attrs.xml` (version 21), `windowActionBar` attributes are not in `<declare-styleable name="Theme">`

Comment: Aha. They mase vesion 21 not backwards compatible in other words. I have not seen that a lot from Google...

Answer (score 0):

if you use intellij => you have to add in /project strutures/modules/ => YOURSDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat and add after in your project
like that you have always the last support

Comment: seems you missed half a sentence. Could you formulate your answer again to make it more understandable, please?