# SwipeRefreshLayout with Material design on Android below 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` with material design on Android 4.0+
[image]

But i see KitKat style refresh animation on Android 4.4 like this
[image]

Is it possible to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` with material design on Android below 5.0?

I read [official post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), but there didn't mention `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: you only need to update the support library to the latest version

Comment: @Blackbelt i use app-compat-v7. And support library has 21.0.3 version (last version)

Comment: you need `com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0`?

Comment: @Blackbelt i just manual replace file in /lib folder. And now has this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655183/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-android-support-v7-appcompat

Comment: no idea, I am sorry. Btw, are you still using eclipse?

Comment: @Blackbelt yep. Do you recommend to use Android Studio?

Comment: @Blackbelt Xavier Ducrohet  said that the Android team will maintain the work on the ADT http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4

Answer (score 0):

1. update android support library to the new version.
2. in your app project replace jar files support-v4.jar and support-v7.jar to the new one and recompile your project.